# POST data to ASP.NET MVC application using AngularJS $http (ionic-framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ionic-framework

I am writing an Ionic app which uses AngularJS and am trying to send a POST to my ASP.NET MVC application.

On my client I have:

```
function testPost(url, token) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var params = {'token': token };

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(data);
    });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

On my server I have:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    string token = (string)Request.Form["token"]; 
}
```

But when debugging my server code, `Request.Form` has no elements. I can form a POST in Postman with `token` set to a value in the body that targets the same action and see that `Request.Form` has a value for `token`. I have tried using `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded' }` and have tried doing `data: JSON.stringify(params)`. I am not sure who is at fault here, my client implementation or server implementation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are posting is not form data. it is json request body. you wont get this data from Request.Form. you will have to either change your client code to send form fields or change your server code to a method that accepts json data as model.

```
public ActionResult Post(ModelOfData data){//do something with data.}
```

Reason it works with postman is you are using content type : form-data
but in javascript you are sending as json request which wont work

Comment: Thanks for making this clarification. Because this is a parameter that will be sent to many actions, I wanted to read it in `OnActionExecuting()` so I am now just looking at the `HttpContext.Request.InputStream` instead of `Request.Form`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use this token for authentication. If you are then you should use custom authorisation filter